# Extjs - is it possible to reset column.hidden to initial state if it was calculated via binding?

Tags: extjs

I need to reset state of grid to the initial state. Some columns are set hidden/visible initially like that:

```
hidden: true / hidden: false
```

but i have also columns that are hidden via binding

```
bind: {
           hidden: '{editMode.active}'
      }
```

or completely without *hidden* property.
it's possible for user to show hidden columns via column picker. So it's pretty easy to reset first type of columns to previous state, as I can copy initial config and set hidden to initial state. But I can't do this with binding or columns without *hidden* property. I've tried with viewModel.notify() to make it to calculate once more, but It doesn't work. I've tried also grid.reconfigure() but as I have some custom columns, I'm getting exceptions when ext tries to reset grid. Is there a way to make ext to calculate this binding once more and override current state of column?

Comment: classic or modern toolkit?

Comment: I use classic one

Answer (score 0):

In case the columns hide/show state is stores in the data of ViewModel, the following code may be useful:

```
var grid = this.up('grid'),
    viewModel = grid.getViewModel(),
    newViewModel = Ext.create(Ext.getClassName(viewModel));
viewModel.setData(newViewModel.getData());
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36tk